# htaccess and custom php cms pretty urls

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I have built a custom PHP, mySQL CMS. The news article links show as this:

https://www.example.com/news/post.php/?p=example-article-slug

However, i want them to show as this:

https://www.example.com/example-article-slug

The below code in the htacess file works but breaks all the other functionality in the htaccess such as the 404 and 301 redirects. Any ideas?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ news/post.php/?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Here's my full htaccess ...

```
            RewriteEngine On 
            RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

            Options -Indexes
            ErrorDocument 201 /404.php
            ErrorDocument 401 /404.php
            ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
            ErrorDocument 402 /404.php
            ErrorDocument 505 /404.php
            ErrorDocument 500 /404.php
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /

            Redirect 301 /oldpage.php   http://www.example.com/

            #Check for www
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

            RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.*/|)(?:index\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
            RewriteRule ^ /%1%2? [R=301,L,NE]

            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ news/post.php/?p=$1 [QSA,L]

            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ news/category/?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Last rule for `news/category/?...` will never trigger because rule before that is sending every non-file/directory to `news/post.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /news/post.php/?p=$1 [L]
```

It will leave you with this URL: `https://www.example.com/example-article-slug`.

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: I used this which works, however it still knocks the rest of the htaccess rules out. I will post my entire htaccess now ...

Comment: The issue isn't with the rule above. It will be one of your other rules knocking it out. I advise commenting everything else out and begin to un-comment and test until you find the rule that is causing the issue. You could also speed up your website by combining some of those rules. For example, the forced `www` and `https`.